# Mixed C/C++ sources, doesn't recognize 'extern' variables on linkage

Tags: c++, c, linker, global-variables, extern

I have the C++ project in which i added some pure C gnu library. I was tasked to change some of the functions, that is used there for the ones, that are needed to be loaded dynamically from dll, so what i did is, i declared the prototype, and made an extern variable:

file **prototypes.h**:

```
typedef char *( __cdecl * _ReParseHtml ) ( DOM * data )
```

file **func_defs.h**

```
extern _ReParseHtml DllReParseHtml;
```

then in my, main file **program.cpp** i declared:

```
_ReParseHtml DllReParseHtml;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("somelib.dll");
    if(hDll != 0){
         DllReParseHtml = (_ReParseHtml)GetProcAddress(hDLL,
                                       "ReParseHtml");
         //etc
    }
}
```

So now i want to use this in the pure `.c` file which i added:
**parser.c**:

```
#include "func_defs.h"  // here is the extern _ReParseHtml DllReParseHtml;

 int create_source(char * buf)
 {
      char * modified = DllReParseHtml(buf);
      // etc..
 }
```

But i get the error `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol DllReParseHtml`.

The function in purce C source `int create_source(char * buf)` from which this functions suppose to be called is not in the `extern "C" { }` block, or anything like that.

Comment: Needs, more, commas, to, be, readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You probably need to add `extern "C"` in your program.cpp, because there you *will* need it. Also you could move `_ReParseHtml DllReParseHtml;` to your parser.c rather than your program.cpp

Comment: @Elijan9 i need to use it elsewhere on the project in a few other C files. Thats why i declared like that

Comment: @KlasLindbäck its not the dll. I just have the `c++` project in which i use some pure C code. In that pure C code i need to access the global variables which is declared in my project. In my post, the global variable is the function that is dynamically loaded from the dll in `WinMain`.

Comment: Did you include the header in your C++ file? If you didn't, the symbol you defined there is a distinct symbol, with internal linkage.

Comment: The header with the `extern _ReParseHtml DllReParseHtml;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, by making all the prototype function declarations as in a block "extern "C" { }" . I had to modify the C code, to the c++ standart, removing some constructions, but at least it helped

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, I do not think your problem comes from the mixing of C and C ++ languages. In fact, a global variable must be declared in a single file without the keyword extern and any other files with that keyword.
Do not change anything in your file "func_def.h" but make sure the typedef is recognized. Take all the same care with C ++ makes a mangle.
Place the beginning of the file directive

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif
```

and at end of file directive

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

In one of your .c files, use the directive

## define extern

This will effectively remove the keyword in a single file.

Regards: Bernard.